# CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs specify limit

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I noticed that [CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx), has no option to limit the amount of records that will be brought back (default 5000). But I did see somewhere if you make a rest call, you can specify a limit. Does anyone know if there is a better way to specify a limit via the official api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListBlobs returns a lazy enumerator, so it will keep making requests to the Blob Service as long as you are enumerating the blobs. If you would like to manage your own requests and handle continuation tokens yourself, you can use [ListBlobsSegmented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmented.aspx) instead and specify the maximum number of blobs to get. However, please note that this is the maximum, so the service can return less than that.

Comment: Thanks, does that do the same thing but just allows you to specify a length?

Comment: Seems that there are api differences between the two and that list blobs takes optional parameters.. It would be really nice if the two had optional parameters.

Comment: var files = _container.ListBlobs(searchPattern, true).OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(blob => blob.ToFileInfo());
return limit.HasValue ? files.Take(limit.Value) : files; what happens if there is no continuation token?

Comment: ListBlobs lists everything. ListBlobsSegmented makes only a single request to the Blob Service. One request can return [0,5000] results.